# I'm able to connect to MongoDB, but not seeing any data from my collections

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I have everything setup and see that I'm connecting successfully, but when trying to use the data in the collection, nothing is there.

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const connectDB = require('./config/db');

const app = express();

connectDB();

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('API Running'));

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); // update to match the domain you will make the request from
    res.header(
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
        'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
    );
    next();
});

app.use(express.json({ extended: false }));

app.use('/api/skateboard_tricks', require('./src/api/skateboard_tricks'));
app.use(
    '/api/general_skate_data/trick_type',
    require('./src/api/general_skate_data')
);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server started on port: ${PORT}`);
});
```

config/db.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const config = require('config');
const db = config.get('mongoURI');

const connectDB = async () => {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(db, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            useCreateIndex: true,
        });

        console.log('MongoDB connected...');
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        process.exit(1);
    }
};

module.exports = connectDB;
```

src/api/skateboard_tricks.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const skate_tricks = require('../models/SkateTrick');

// @route   GET api/skateboard_tricks
// @desc    skateboard tricks data
// @access  public

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    skate_tricks.find({}, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            const trick_list = result[0];
            res.send(trick_list.tricks);
        }
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

API call in the app

```
    const [trickList, setTrickList] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    const sfsApiCall = axios.create({
        baseURL: 'http://localhost:5000/',
    });

    const getTrickData = async () => {
        try {
            const data = await sfsApiCall.get('api/skateboard_tricks').then((res) => {
                console.log(res);
                setTrickList(res.data);
            });
            setLoading(true);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err.message);
        }
    };
    
    useEffect(() => {
        getTrickData();
    }, [loading]);
```

This used to work a while back and I'm revisiting the code now and it's not working anymore. Not sure what happened tbh.

Postman screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIcok.png

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I created a separate app to isolate the API connection files and it looks like I'm getting a network error. This is from Postman:

```
GET http://localhost:5000/api/skateboard_tricks
Error: read ECONNRESET
Request Headers
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.28.4
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: 9da940c6-62bc-437e-bb07-d0457368264a
Host: localhost:5000
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
```

This error is showing in the console

```
GET http://localhost:5000/api/skateboard_tricks net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED 200
```

This might be a CORS issue, but even troubleshooting that isn't clear to me. Hope this can help someone help me.

Comment: any errors in the console etc?

Comment: I was going to ask, what is the response for the network call from the Network tab in the browser inspector?

Comment: @RobertTerrell There are no errors in the console or network tab. i have a console.log showing the response data and it gives me the 200 code, but nothing in the data field.

Comment: @frishi There are no errors in the network tab. i am getting a 200 code, but the response has no data.

Comment: Please try putting a `console.log(trick_list)` in your `else` block in your API call and see if there's any data coming through.

Comment: @Sako is there data in your collection?

Comment: @RobertTerrell Yes, there is data. As I mentioned before, this worked a few months ago, but for some reason the data is not being pulled in this time. I checked to make sure I'm calling on the correct collection and everything.

Comment: @frishi Here is the output of the console.log in the API call: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yA2sR.png

Comment: @Sako In your response, the `data` key is empty. Even though your response is a 200 OK, there is no data coming through from mongo. Separately, as you pointed out in your edit, try fixing the CORS error first. That is most likely, the culprit here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so for whatever reason, I was no longer able to get the data from the trick object in the skateboard_tricks.js file. I had to specify the trick object when calling the function to pull the data in my app (see OP for comparison).

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const skate_tricks = require('../models/SkateTrick');

// @route   GET api/skateboard_tricks
// @desc    skateboard tricks data
// @access  public

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    skate_tricks.find({}, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            const trick_list = result[0];
            res.send(trick_list);
        }
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Notice where `res.send(trick_list)` no longer has `.tricks` tied to it. Here is the code in the API call:

```
    const [trickList, setTrickList] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    const sfsApiCall = axios.create({
        baseURL: 'http://localhost:5000/',
    });

    const getTrickData = async () => {
        try {
            const data = await sfsApiCall.get('api/skateboard_tricks').then((res) => {
                setTrickList(res.data.tricks);
            });
            setLoading(true);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err.message);
        }
    };
    
    useEffect(() => {
        getTrickData();
    }, [loading]);
```

Note that I'm now referencing `res.data.tricks` in `setTrickList`. I spent 2 days on this stupid error so I hope this post can help someone else.

Thanks to everyone that chimed in. I feel like it all still helped to troubleshoot. This code was last worked on 8 months ago so it's likely one of the dependencies got updated to require this workaround when I updated all of my npm packages.

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing this locally, you can use some browser extensions to disable CORS restrictions:

1. For Chrome, https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en
2. For Firefox, https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cors-unblock/
3. For Safari, you can check `Develop > Disable Cross-Origin Restrictions`

These extensions will help you disable CORS entirely and you can sanely check if the API is returning data the way you expect it.

Note that this is purely for development and testing purposes. You should set up your API with the correct CORS configuration and then pass along the right headers in your request from the UI.

See: http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html